# Conditional probability and its expectation of continuous random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I have two subtle questions on the definition of conditional probability and its expectation. Here's the thing.

Question 1.

Definition of a conditional probability density function

$f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$

And if I want to compute below probability:

$P(0<X<1|0<Y<2)$

then I think below equation is one to calculate:

$P(0<X<1|0<Y<2)=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}f(x,y)dydx}{\int_{0}^{2}f_{Y}(y)dy}$

and come to think of it. How about this:

$P(0<X<1|0<Y<2)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}f_{X|Y}(x|y)dydx$

But it is easy to show that

$\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}f(x,y)dydx}{\int_{0}^{2}f_{Y}(y)dy} \neq \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}f_{X|Y}(x|y)dydx$

Where are the parts that I am missing at all?

Question 2.

The *conditional expectation* of $X$, given that $Y=y$, is defined for all values of $y$ such that $f_Y(y)>0$, by

$E[X|Y=y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$

Here's my question.

Since we are dealing with continuous random variable cases, we've learned that a value of a pdf at a particular point is meaningless since $P(X=a)=0$, where $X$ is a continuous one.

But, as you can see in the definition of conditional expectation, the given condition is $Y=y$ not that $Y$ is in some interval or something like that.

I don't see why it is a valid definition.

p.s. The text book is *Introduction to Probability Models 10th Ed*. by Sheldon M. Ross.

Comment: Re 1., there is no reason to expect that $P(X\in A\mid Y\in B)=\int_A\int_Bf_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)dydx$, actually, $\int_Af_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)dx=P(X\in A\mid Y=y)$ and $P(X\in A\mid Y\in B)$ is not $\int_BP(X\in A\mid Y=y)dy$ but $\int_BP(X\in A\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)dy$. Re 2., note that $E(X\mid Y=y)$ is actually a shorthand for $u(y)$, where $u$ can be any function such that $E(X\mid Y)=u(Y)$ almost surely. IOW, to really understand this formula, one needs the true definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: What is $f(x,y) $ in your case ?

Comment: Is $E(X|Y=y)$ meaningful? If $Y$ is a continuous random variable, $Y=y$ does not seem that meaningful...